# Widgets not appearing on Droid Razr

Tags: android, widget

I have an app that displays static widgets, but doesn't work on the Droid Razr. I can not figure it out for the life of me, as my coding skills are amateur at best.

The widgets are on the homescreen, but they are invisible. You can move them around, but they just don't display.

Basically my app has multiple widgets, and it has worked fine in other android versions. I'm not concerned so much about my awful coding, but more making sure it works for the Razr. (Although tips would be much appreciated!)

Democrat.java

```
 package demo.crat.widgets;

    import android.app.Activity;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class democrat extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        }

}
```

Then I have another java file for each widget (which I'm sure is not proper coding)

W1.java

```
    package demo.crat.widgets;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;

public class W1 extends AppWidgetProvider {
}
```

I understand how to edit all the res files so I haven't included them.

Below is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="demo.crat.widgets"
      android:versionCode="4"
      android:versionName="1.3">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

      <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".democrat"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget updates -->
        <receiver android:icon="@drawable/w1" android:name=".W1" android:label="@string/string1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action  android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:resource="@xml/hello_widget_provider" />
        </receiver>
        <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget updates -->
        <receiver android:icon="@drawable/w2" android:name=".W2" android:label="@string/string2">
            <intent-filter>
                <action  android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
android:resource="@xml/hello_widget_provider2" />
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I assume it has something to do with not having an OnUpdate() in democrat.java? Any help would be much appreciated!